# "Welcome" of "Finish registration" letter in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

When a user is created through the Keycloak admin console, is there a way to notify a user via email that a profile has been created and the user can finish registration following by a link?
Currently, the user can get an email about profile being created only if after creation a password had been set for the user. And only after an initial login attempt. But for this login attempt, the user should know the password that was set.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I accomplished the same thing by customizing the keycloak theme templates for the emails sent and for the login pages.  Here's  the [Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes) on how to customize the themes.

Here's the specifics of how I did it:

**First, I customized the executeActions.ftl email template** to be pretty and say "welcome to our application, click the link below to finish setting up your account".  I continued to use the link and link expiration note from the default base template. You can see the default base template at https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/email/html/executeActions.ftl

**Second, we decided what standard keycloak actions would be "required" for new users**.  We decided that to finish registration, users would be required to do these actions:

1. Accept Terms and Condition
2. Enter their full name (Update their profile)
3. Setup a new password

**Third, we setup our Keycloak realm to require all users go through the 3 steps.**
In the Keycloak admin console, we set these up as "Required" actions (under Configure-->Authentication-->Required Actions), marking the "Terms and Conditions", "Update Profile" and "Update Password" actions as "Enabled" and  "Default Action". We also put these actions in  the exact order that we wanted them to appear in the "account setup" process that the user would go through screen by screen. For the other actions, we  unchecked Default Action. 
[image]

**Fourth, I customized the following keycloak login templates that render the account setup pages.** The keycloak-generated link that was embedded in the executeActions email (from step 1) will take the user to these "account setup" web pages:

- **info.ftl**  - The default is [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/info.ftl). After clicking the link in the welcome email, the user ends up on a page generated by this template. This page usually renders web pages that display generic informational messages of all kinds, 
  but it also renders the FIRST and LAST page of the account setup process. So I modified it to check to see if the message.summary matched the first step or last step of the account setup process. If it was the first step, I'd render 'welcome' text on the page. If it was the last step, I'd render something like 'your account has been setup. Click here to login'.  See below for how I modified info.ftl.

```
<!-- info.ftl -->
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayMessage=false; section>

  <#if section = "header">
    <#if messageHeader??>
      ${messageHeader}
    <#else>
      <#if message.summary == msg('confirmExecutionOfActions')>
        ${kcSanitize(msg('welcomeToOurApplication'))?no_esc}
      <#elseif message.summary == msg('accountUpdatedMessage')>
        ${kcSanitize(msg('accountSuccessfullySetup'))?no_esc}
      <#else>
        ${message.summary}
      </#if>
    </#if>

  <#elseif section = "form">
    <div id="kc-info-message">
      <div class="kc-info-wrapper">
        <#if message.summary == msg('confirmExecutionOfActions')>
          ${kcSanitize(msg('startSettingUpAccount'))?no_esc}
        <#elseif message.summary == msg('accountUpdatedMessage')>
          ${kcSanitize(msg('accountIsReadyPleaseLogin'))?no_esc}
        <#else>
          ${message.summary}
        </#if>
      </div>

      <#if pageRedirectUri??>

       ... <!-- Omitted the rest because it's the same as the base template -->
```

I also customized the following templates, that correspond to steps in the account setup process.

- **terms.ftl**  - shows terms & conditions step
- **login-update-profile.ftl** - shows the step where the user needs to enter/update his/her full name
- **login-updated-password.ftl** - prompts user to change password.

**Fifth, when the administrator creates a new user, he/she triggers the welcome email being sent to the user:**
 - In the Keycloak admin console, once you "Add" a new user, go to that user's "Credentials" tab, and under Credential Reset select the account setup actions required under "Reset Actions" and then click the "Send email" button.

[image: List item]

Anyway, I hope this helps. I remember it taking me a little while to figure out because it is not a standard flow within keycloak.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply. I came up to this flow as well, but it seems a bit hacky, and I was hoping that there was a better way of doing this out of the box.

Comment: I believe you can use the keycloak api to send the verification email, which might remove the need for someone to send the email.

Comment: Yes, triggering the email can be done with the API: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html look for `/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email`